# Spring AutoPopulatinglist issue

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-webflow

I am adding elements dynamically using java script(Adding textboxes when we click add).Each of this textbox would be an element of a bList in my domain class.
See Below

Code:

```
Class A
{

Approach1
List<B> bList= LazyList.decorate(
            new ArrayList<B>(), new InstantiateFactory(
                    B.class));

Approach2
List<B> bList= new AutoPopulatingList(B.class)

}
```

So basically i am trying to add elements to bList.
I know that i need to use autopopulatinglist or lazy list.But neither of these work.When i try to post the form it complains telling that collection has 0 elements and the index is invalid.
Is the above declaration enuf to ensure that i have the list ready to add elements.
Also when i read about using autopopulating list.Ref: http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=12

It says that we have to change the formBackingObject method in the controller to instantiate a new AutoPopulatingList:

Code:

```
 ShoppingBasketForm sbf = new ShoppingBasketForm(); 
      sbf.setItems(new AutoPopulatingList(ShoppingBasketItem.class));
```

But i am using spring webflow not spring MVC, So where exactly i put this logic.

Even if i try to access `<form:input path="bList[0]" />` it would complain

Please advice.

Comment: Please take some time to format your question correctly before posting it. Regular text starts at the beginning of the line. Use the preview to check that everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-990 <-- look at this issue.